# Example showing that direct image functor is not right exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I was reading Grauert and Remmert coherent analytic sheaves there is an example showing that $f_*$ is not a exact function, the example is the following one

Take $X=\mathbb{C}^2 \backslash\{0\}$ and $Y=\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y$ are the ordinary sheaves of holomorphic functions. Denote by
$$
\varphi: \mathbb{C}^2 \backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\left(x_1, x_2\right) \mapsto x_1,
$$
the projection and by $X_0 \subset X$ the inverse image of $0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $X_0$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}^*$.

If $\mathcal{I}$ is the sheaf of ideal of $X_0$ , we obtain the canonical exact sequence
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{X}} \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{X}} / {\mathcal{I}} \rightarrow \mathrm{0}
$$

but the induced homomorphism
$$
\varphi_*{ }a: \varphi_*{ }\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \varphi_*\left(\mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}\right)
$$
is not surjective.

---

I can't really understand this example, by definition one needs to show that it's not stalkwise surjective after taking $\varphi_*$, however I can't prove it clearly.

Comment: I think it is due to Harthogs lemma that the stalk at $0$ on the left are holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C$, whereas on the right you get holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^*$.

Comment: thank you @red_trumpet , I can get the feeling, however I don't know what's the elements in the quotient sheaf $\mathcal{O}/\mathcal{I}$ and what's the stalk of the $\varphi_*(\mathcal{F})$, can you show more details?

Comment: We have $\mathcal O_X/I = \mathcal O_{X_0}$, so those are holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^*$. As that sheaf is supported on a single fiber, the stalk of the push-forward is just global sections. For $\varphi_* \mathcal O_X$, you have to take the (co?)limit of $\mathcal O_X(\varphi^{-1}U)$, where $U$ runs over neighborhoods of zero. By Harthogs lemma, $\mathcal O_X(\varphi^{-1}U)=\mathcal O(U\times \mathbb C)$.

Comment: Thank you red_trumpet, I will write down the solution based on the comment later.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use your favorite example showing global sections isn’t exact, since global sections is essentially the same as pushing forward to a point.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel , I am not sure, do we needs some condition to let global sections the same as pushing forward to a point? For example properness condition?

Comment: @yili We don't need any conditions on the map. We're just exploiting the fact that given a constant map $X \to \{y\}$, the preimage of $\{y\}$ is all of $X$.

Comment: Oh thank you @Daniel  I see, I remember that for proper morphism one can take $$\left(R^i f_{\star} \mathscr{F}\right)_y \cong H^i\left(f^{-1}(y), \mathscr{F}\right) .$$Does the higher direct image needs the properness condition?

Comment: @yili It also does not need properness, if I understand what you're asking. In general, given a constant map $p: X \to \{y\}$, it can be shown that $R^ip_\star(\mathscr{F})$ is the sheaf on $\{y\}$ associated to $H^i(X, \mathscr{F})$.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help Daniel